Running a trading algorithm- On-premise vs Cloud
I am seeking detailed information to evaluate the suitability of on-premises and cloud-based solutions for deploying and managing a trading algorithm.
Requirements:
Which is more reliable- On-premises infrastructure or cloud solutions?
What type of hardware should I use, processors, GPUs, storage, memory, parallel ports, etc.? Can you provide examples of any successful implementations in similar use cases?

Hello there. If you require any specific information, feel free to reach out to me.

This site works best with just one question per post.

Hey Suandrip, without substantially more information about the needs and characteristics of your specific trading algorithm, we can't really answer this question effectively. Please provide specific examples of the trading algorithms you plan to deploy, ideally with performance benchmarks based on your usage. Thanks!

My question is resolved. Thanks to all for the answers.
